# When can client code know about strategy pattern implementations?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, abstract-class, strategy

[image: strategy pattern]

I am considering using a strategy pattern for configuration file management, that way I can support some legacy configs.  I feel pretty solid on the overall design (as its pretty standard strategy pattern), but I am curious if the client should know the type of strategy that is being implemented or if that violates the strategy pattern.   Specifically the ConfigurationParser constructor requires an istream and a string (or maybe enum) of the type of stream it is (xml, json, ini, etc.) to know which concrete strategy to instantiate.

Ideally I would like to just pass the istream, but if I do that then I probably have to put in code in the ConfigurationParser to discern the stream type by looking for angle brackets vs square brackets or something of the sort.

I decided to not pass a string file path and determine type from extension because the legacy stuff isnt always consistent in extension naming and it makes my code a lot easier to test if I pass streams instead of hard coding file paths.

Comment: Which is more important to you: the ability to know what kind of stream it is so that you can process it properly, or the need for a higher degree of decoupling?

Comment: My gut reaction is the need for a higher degree of decoupling.

Comment: Cool.  So how will you solve the problem of processing the stream properly?  Or is that largely irrelevant?

Comment: Haven't gotten that far.

Comment: You might consider weighing the pros and cons, instead of just relying on your gut.  High decoupling does you no good if the system can't perform its essential functions.  I consider "correctness" of secondary importance.

Comment: You can encapsulate the details in a simple factory. It's often used with strategy to insulate clients.

Comment: You cannot "violate a pattern", since patterns are simply ideas for creating your own custom solution.

Comment: @FrankHileman: honestly, this sounds nitty. To my understanding, it is perfectly possible to violate the "strategy pattern by the book". I guess what you really meant is "violating a pattern is not necessarily a bad thing" (if the own solution is still a good one). However, in this case, by implementing the code for picking the right strategy subclass directly in the `ConfigurationParser`, not the strategy pattern itself would be "violated", but the SRP. The solution for this was already mentioned by T.C. below, namely injecting a factory into the parser.

Comment: @DocBrown patterns are supposed to be higher level structures than specific code implementations, to express things that limitations in the language etc make difficult to reuse as library constructs. So one pattern implementation is never more correct than another. That is all I meant.

Comment: @FrankHileman: you are correct about what patterns are, nevertheless your logic is flawed. The fact a pattern is a high-level solution, or the fact the same pattern can be implemented in different variants does not prevent one to implement a pattern in a wrong way. For example, the strategy pattern has a clear desciption in the GoF book, and it has the purpose of decoupling the "context" from a concrete strategy. If I make an attempt implementation but introduce something which invalidates the decoupling, it is IMHO sensible to say "I violate the (purpose of) the pattern".

Comment: @DocBrown you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks to me that you have two different problems. Problem A is easy to solve. But problem B is harder.

**Problem A is to dynamically call a given strategy given a configString.** That can be solved by creating a Map and pairing an instance of each parser with a string that identifies it. That way you just fetch from the Map the parser you need. If the parser is too costly to instantiate, you can put in the Map a builder for that parser instead. This solution assumes that the final user (or you) knows what type of configuration file is going to be parsed.

Obviously, to achieve total decoupling, a factory should set up the whole Map of parsers (or parser builder) and the client should have this Map passed to it. That way only the factory is hard coupled to the concrete parsers.

**Problem B is that you want to automatically determine what kind of file (or istream) you are reading to use the appropiate parser**, i.e., the final user (or you) will not select the file and tell the app the type of conf file.

**A solution for problem B** is to have all parsers in a List and iterate through it. When one parser fails to parse the stream, go to the next parser and so on. If a parser successfully parses the stream, end of story (you can report what parser you finally used if you add a name field to the parsers). If every parser fails then the file is not supported by any parser. You don't need to investigate inside the stream to guess the format, let the parsers try to parse it. One potential problem I see with this solution is that it is possible that two different parsers could interpret the same input format in different ways without failing. In that case the first parser that does will always do the work and it may not be the one you expected.

A log output could look like this:

```
Parsing: unknown_config_file
..not XML
..not JSON
..successfully parsed using "ini" parser.
```

or

```
Parsing: unknown_config_file
..not XML
..not JSON
..not ini
..unsuported config file.
```

Comment: Very good answer. Side note: if two different parsers could interpret the same input format in different ways without failing, not even a person can easily tell which format it is. Or, this person has additional information available, like context information or the file extension. Then this additional information can be passed to the ConfigurationParser's constructor as well.